# Get output from mplayer slave mode to file

Tags: shell, pipe, fifo, mplayer

I ran `mplayer -slave -quiet -idle -input file=/tmp/fifo file.mp3` in `screen`. 
Now when I use `echo 'get_property volume' > /tmp/fifo` I need to get volume value to .txt file. How can I do this? Somebody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The volume is printed on the terminal by `mplayer`. You need to grep for it and put the result in a file. Here is one way of doing it with `bash`:

```
mplayer -slave -quiet -idle -input file=/tmp/fifo file.mp3 \
| tee >(grep --line-buffered ^ANS_volume= > /tmp/volume.txt)
```

If you send multiple commands, you need to consider only the last line of `/tmp/volume.txt`:

```
tail -n1 /tmp/volume.txt
```

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately this doesn't work. `/tmp/volume.txt` is blank.

Comment: @trapczyk I tested this. Maybe the string to `grep` is not the same with your version of `mplayer`. What does it print when you request `get_property volume`?

Comment: I have checked this before and get_property prints this same - `ANS_volume` e.g  `ANS_volume=90.909088`

Comment: @trapczyk Hmmm, weird. Let's try first without the `tee`: `mplayer ... | grep --line-buffered ^ANS_volume= > /tmp/volume.txt`. Is the ANS_volume message still displayed? If not, is it in the `volume.txt` file?

Comment: When I removed tee, ANS_volume isn't displayed after `echo 'get_property volume' > /tmp/fifo` (but is displayed in `screen -r sessionname`) and also isn't in volume.txt file.

Comment: @trapczyk To debug this, I suggest you put everything in `/tmp/volume.txt` (i.e. `mplayer > /tmp/volume.txt`), you send your commands through your FIFO, you stop mplayer and check out `/tmp/volume.txt`: are the `ANS_volume` lines in there? can you grep the file with my grep parameters?

Comment: Is possible reason of this is that I've Raspbian OS (Debian 8 Jessie) and I need to install some libs or something?

Comment: So I have tried `mplayer -slave -quiet -idle -input file=/tmp/fifo file.mp3 > /home/pi/Desktop/output.txt`, sent commands through FIFO `echo 'get_property volume' > /tmp/fifo`, stopped mplayer as you said and txt file is empty.